# what are the fields of the 'ls -l' call under bash

Tags: bash

What are the fields in listed order when one makes the call: ls -l in a bash shell.  First I know is file type and permissions, next are a series of 4 integers that I do not know or am uncertain about, then is a date permissions were assigned then another integer and a time, then finally the file name.  What I really want to know is what are the 4 integers between file permissions and permission assignment dates? The assignment dates follow a format of, ie "Oct 2 03:15"?

Comment: This question may be better suited to [unix.se]

Comment: you could do a `man ls`

Comment: @hetepeperfan on my system this doesn't contain a useful description.

Comment: The try `info coreutils 'ls invocation'`.

Comment: I am playing with my android system and the system response is "bash:  info: command not found"

Comment: Well if info's not installed and you get a number for owner's group and user, this probably means you have a corrupt gnu/linux installation.

Comment: Then try https://google.com/search?query=man+ls or https://google.com/search?query=coreutils+info+ls

Answer (score 1):

Considering the four integers you mention:

1. Hard Link Count. See [this](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2011/04/15/counting-and-listing-hard-links-on-linux/) site.
2. Group of the user that
   owns the file. Shouldn't be a number. If you get a number on your
   system this would be a non-standard.
3. User that owns the file. Again, shouldn't be a number.
4. File size

Comment: It is a number and it is actually bash under malvics (?)  because it is android os

Comment: Malvics ? what's malvics ? Google has nothing about this word.

Comment: I the end point here is to gain use of utilities in.my sbin folder on the droid and there are 2 links user and group i am assuming, then PS 0  is the user and group who own sbin and size is listed as 0.  I am assuming the size is hidden.

Comment: I think you mean Dalvik. I stop here, never used Android in command line level. Maybe in this case the numbers are right then.

Comment: thank you all. i did not know this was not the site to ask this question. sorry.